# char check that contains letters and digits

Tags: c#, char

I have a name in char type, I am currently using the

```
    public bool IsBroken() => _name.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

to check if it contains only letters and numbers.

problem is I have names in this form A.A.A with . in the middle, do you have an idea on how I can authorize the . also with letters and numbers

Comment: Are multiple consecutive dots allowed? Is there a max on how many dots are allowed. At some point if its gets more complex you might want think about checking via a regex.

Comment: ^^ Maybe provide a complete rendition of the format requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public bool IsBroken() => _name.Any(c => !(char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '.'));
```

Comment: OP writes that the dot is in the middle. This will also pass names where the dot is at the start or at the end.

Comment: ^^ and also consecutive dots "A..A"

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to define some rules on the names that contain the periods. If a name starts or ends with a period then the method should return true because that name is broken, also if two consecutive periods are in a name then it should also return true that the name is broken. My code below checks for consecutive periods, periods at the beginning or end and character entries that are not a number or a letter in the input string.

```
public bool IsBroken(string _name)
{
    //check if a name starts or ends with a period
    if (_name.StartsWith(".") || _name.EndsWith("."))
    {
        return true; 
    }

    bool previousIsPeriod = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _name.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = _name[i];
         //check for non letter and non number characters 
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) && !char.Equals(c, '.'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //check for consecutive periods in the name 
        if (char.Equals(c, '.'))
        {
            if (previousIsPeriod)
            {
                return true;
            }

            previousIsPeriod = true;
        }
        else
        {
            previousIsPeriod = false;
        }
    }
    //return false if the name is valid 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking that using [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0).

```
public bool IsBroken() => !Regex.IsMatch(_name, @"^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[A-Z]\.)+$");
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JbK0Ze) is a demo.